# Perl: General way of finding size of block device

Tags: perl, block-device

I use `-s` regularly to find the size of a file. It works cross platform.

Is there a similar well tested way of finding the size of a block device?

We are not talking the size of a filesystem or the free space on a file system, but the size of the actual block device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
perl -e 'seek(STDIN,0,2); print tell(STDIN);' < /dev/sda
```

and looks fairly portable. Requires root.

It would be good to find a solution that does not require root.

Tested on: Linux, CygWin.

Comment: On OpenBSD: `... </dev/sda` - `ksh: cannot open /dev/sda: No such file or directory`.  With `... </dev/sd0a`: `ksh: cannot open /dev/sd0a: Permission denied`.  As root, `... </dev/sd0a`: `ksh: cannot open /dev/sd0a: Device busy`.  As root, `... </dev/rsd0a`: `0`.  Not particularly useful. :) Good question though.

Comment: If you find a solution that works on OpenBSD, please post it.

Comment: Does the "Device busy" also apply to unmounted devices?

Comment: No, but the result is still 0.  As I said, it's a good question. :)